# After upgrading to Ubuntu22.04 my bluetooth manager stopped working. İt cannot see any device at all

Tags: bluetooth-speaker

Bluetooth is not working on Toshiba L55D

Comment: You've not provided many specifics; are you using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop.. and are you using the GA kernel stack or HWE stack?  (*default stack set by your install media*).  If it's kernel related for example & you upgraded from 20.04 LTS (*you didn't specify*) which was using the HWE kernel, the GA kernel stack is 5.15 which was the HWE stack of 20.04 (ie. you could switch to the prior kernel as one option if that's the cause).  If it was updated *bluetooth* software however that won't likely change anything. What was the *upgrade*? Are you using Server? Desktop?

Comment: Please look in `journalctl -b -0 -r -u bluetooth` and `dmesg`